# Sorting in to columns

Tags: excel

I need to put the date of column A in Column B. This is just a sample, I have more than 1,000 records.

[image]

Comment: look into text to Columns in the data tab.

Comment: Thanks for your help sit this worked very well

Comment: Will the starting position of Date remain same?

Comment: Yeah, @ScottCraner's got it - just use Text to Columns with a `|` delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

**Option 1: Import and Parse your Raw Data**

It looks like your data is delimited by the pipe (`|`) character. You can import your raw data file into excel, and parse it. Use the following steps to import your data. This will create columns for your ID, Date, Name, and Info fields.

- On the DATA ribbon choose "From Text" in the "Get External Data"
  section.
- Choose your raw file
- Choose Delimited
- Check "My Data has Headers"
- Set Delimiters = Other "|"
- format any columns if needed

**Option 2: Parse your existing data in column A using Text to Columns**

As suggested in the comments by @Scott Craner, you can use the "Text to columns" option in the Data tab to parse your data using the following steps:

- Select column A
- Click "Text to Columns" in the Data tab
- Under Delimiters, uncheck everything except "Other" and set the character to "|".
- Click next, then format your columns as desired. You can click on your second column and format it as a date if you wish.
- Click finish, and then OK to paste the data in place.

**Option 3: Parse your data using a formula**

If you insist on using a formula to parse your data in column A, you can paste the following formula into cell B1 and copy down:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("|",A1,1)+1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,1)+1)-(FIND("|",A1,1)+1)))
```

This formula looks for the first and second occurrences of the pipe (`|`) character, and grabs the text in between. It then uses the `Trim()` function to remove whitespace before or after the text.